# I have provided a authorization is security for page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am new in salesforce. I have created a page in my page i Have one form with standard controller.

When I run that page I got this error --

```
Authorization Required 

You must first log in or register before accessing this page. 
If you have forgotten your password, click Forgot Password to reset it.
```

I tried to add a visualforce page for my site. But it is not working fine.

Please help me !!

Comment: Did you add the page to the site public settings or are you trying to access or save a type of object that is not publicly accessible ?

Comment: Your question is unclear; it sounds like you embedded your new page, but you don't say where it is or how it is supposed to be used. Is this for a public site or portal? Which object is the page for?

Comment: @Sdry: I created a page called home. After that I configure site and given this page as a default page. After this I created one form in same page, then its showing Authorization error. I checked security tab in apex classes but still getting same.

Comment: @Mike: i just started salesforce. Simply I created one page and added one form on that. After that I am trying to access my site through given url..but its showing above error...

Answer (score 2):

This error usually results from any type of error within the controller's logic. Instead of showing an error message, the system simply shows a "not authorized" error. You may want to go to Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs, add the Guest Site User to the debug log list, and then visit your home page on the site. This should generate a debug log that you can check in the same area.

If that fails, try loading your page as a normal (non-admin) user in salesforce.com, and see if they get an error. You can use this information to try and narrow down the cause of the error. You should also note that sharing rules and profile permissions may also be the cause of the error. You can check the permissions under Setup > Develop > Sites > (Site Name) > Public Access Settings. Make sure your code is not attempting to access any fields or objects that the profile is not configured for.