# Site that should be available to all Internet users gives "Authorization Required" error

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites, authorization

I have a site that should be available to any user that hits a site.  Debug logs are of no help debugging this issue, as I have tried capturing them while the issue is in process for a user, and there are no errors or exceptions logged. It gives "Authorization required error" when a user enters all the information and clicks submit. The page has also been added to the list of Visualforce pages. The user also has access to the object that is being queried. Any thoughts are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See answers such as http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13496/i-have-provided-a-authorization-is-security-for-page#23966

Comment: Have you set the correct permissions in your sites profile? It maybe that there is an object or field that you are trying to access/set that the sites profile doesnt have permissions too.

Comment: Hey Francis,Thanks for responding. Any particular site permissions ? The object and the field are given full access. Even the page has been added to the list of Site Visualforce pages.